# How Can I See My Shard ID for KCL in My AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sharding, amazon-kcl

I'm new to AWS Kinesis.
I'm trying to work with KCL version 1 (following the amazon instructions here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-implementation-app-java.html#kcl-java-interface-original)

I want to initialize a new KCL instance, but I don't know what my shard ID is. My console shows I have 1 active.

I'm trying to find it in my amazon console but can't.
Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know?

Answer (score -1):

You can list all the shardId's in your Kinesis stream with the AWS CLI:

```
aws kinesis describe-stream --stream-name STREAM_NAME
```

Assuming you have created a new stream with 1 shard and have not made any split's or merges, your shardId should be "shardId-000000000000".